# How to parse netstat output and extract the fourth column

Tags: regex, perl

How can I parse out the fourth column of `netstat` instead of the first column?

Also, how can I use `mailx` to send an email alert if a connection drops below the expected IP count?

Code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %minimum = (
    '101.101.101.101:2000' => 2,
    '101.101.101.102:3000' => 5,
);

my %count;

open my $fh, '-|', 'netstat -an' or die "could not run netstat: $!";

while( <$fh> ) {
    next unless /^([0-9.]+:\d+000) /;
    $count{$1}++;
}

close $fh;

while ( my ($ip_port, $min) = each %minimum ) {
    $count{$ip_port} ||= 0;
    next if $count{$ip_port} >= $min;
    print "$ip_port: need $min connections, found only  $count{$ip_port}\n";
}
```

Here is the output from `netstat`

```
tcp 0 0 ::ffff:101.101.101.101:2000 ::ffff:10.151.89.57:8030 ESTABLISHED
```

I'm trying to get the above script to look at the fourth column

```
ffff:101.101.101.101:2000
```

and if that address doesn't appear twice then alert.

The same concept for `10.101.101.102:3000` which should appear no less than five times in column four of the `netstat` output.

Comment: You want to split your input to get columns as an array. There is also a module for netstat on cpan. If you have more than one question, please ask them separately.

Comment: @simbabque here is my output from my netstat environment:
`tcp 0 0 ::ffff:101.101.101.101:2000 ::ffff:10.151.89.57:8030 ESTABLISHED` I'm trying to get the above script to look at the 4th column `ffff:101.101.101.101:2000` and if `101.101.101.101:2000` doesn't exit 2 times then alert. same concept for 10.101.101.102:3000 which should exits no less than 5 times from the netstat output of column 4

Comment: There is nothing in the code that you show that could access the fourth column. Please show what you've written to solve this problem. Stack Overflow is neither a tutorial site nor a place to get code written for free.

Comment: @ Borodin it is this piece of code:
`^([0-9.]+:\d+000` I needed help with the regex piece of it which I would think stackoverflow would be used for...

Comment: @connollyc4: I seriously doubt that you wrote that yourself. Writing software isn't done by snagging a likely-looking piece of code from the internet and posting it back up in the hope that someone else will finish your job for you. If you're unable to do your job then find something that you *can* do.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking why your code isn't working, it's clearly because you anchor your regex pattern `/^([0-9.]+:\d+000) /` to  the start of the string. There is no IPv6 address there in your sample data.

Please add information by *editing* your question. It is all but useless in comments.

Here's how I would write your code. There's no reason to open a handle to a pipe

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my %minimum = (
    '101.101.101.101:2000' => 2,
    '101.101.101.102:3000' => 5,
);

my %count;

/\b([0-9.]+:\d+000)\b/ and ++$count{$1} for `netstat -an`;

while ( my ( $ip_port, $min ) = each %minimum ) {
    my $n = $count{$ip_port} // 0;
    print "$ip_port: need $min connections, found only  $n\n" if $n < $min;
}
```